# Scala implicit parameters need to be repeated?

Tags: scala, implicit

I have the following simple test-case:

```
trait Printable[T] {
  val string: String
  def print() = println("It works: " + string)
}

def foo[T](x: T)(implicit ev: T => Printable[T]) = {
  x.print()
}

implicit def doubleToPrint(x: Double): Printable[Double] = new Printable[Double] {
  override val string: String = x.toString
}

foo(2.0) // => It works: 2.0
```

However, creating a new function `bar[T](x: T)` which should call `foo(x)` raises an error that there is no implicit view available from `T => Printable[T]` :

```
// this does not work
def bar[T](x: T) = {
  println("Some other stuff")
  foo(x)
}
```

However, when adding the same parameter it works ofcourse:

```
// this does work
def bar[T](x: T)(implicit ev: T => Printable[T]) = {
  println("Some other stuff")
  foo(x)
}
```

It seems to me quite cumbersome to keep chaining these implicit parameters, because I was under the assumption that the `foo` function will start searching for the implicit conversion and not the function `bar` calling `foo`. As I understand the `implicit def doubleToPrint` should be in scope for `foo` also when it is being called from within `foo`.

What am I overlooking?

**Additional question in response to the answer of dth**

So I understand the answer, which is actually very logical.
However, the solution of the context bounds does not work in the situation where `foo` and `bar` are both part of another trait, since context bounds are not allowed in traits:

```
// not allowed to do trait FooBar[T : Printable]
trait FooBar[T] {
    def foo(x: T)(implicit ev: T => Printable[T]) = {
        println("Running foo...")
        x.print()
    }

    // this is not allowed
    def bar(x: T) = {
        println("But running bar first...")
        foo(x)
    }
}
```

So is it also possible to solve this without using the implicit parameter?

**My own, not so nice, solution**

I came to the conclusion that I actually don't need a trait in my specific code and can replace the `FooBar[T]` trait with an `abstract class FooBar[T <% Printable[T]]`.

It is a solution for my problem, but not the additional question I added.

Comment: View bounds are deprecated, so you should use a context bound, even though it is a little bit more complicated in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think about, how implicit parameters work:

When you call a method requiring an implicit parameter somewhere the compiler looks in the context (scope, involved types) for a suitable implicit.

Now look at your definition of bar:

```
def bar[T](x: T) = {
  foo(x)
}
```

When you call foo the compiler looks for an implicit value of the type `T => Printable[T]` which it cannot find. It does not matter, that you will call bar later with a type Double as it does not know that.

So the answer is yes, you have to pass implicit parameters around everywhere, where you can not find a suitable value in the context (so usually everywhere, where you do not know the concrete type).

There is however syntactic sugar called context bounds, so you can define bar like this:

```
def bar[T: Printable](x: T) = foo(x)
```

You could also define foo like this and use `implicitly[Printable[T]]` to access the values. So you do not have to concern yourself with implicit parameters at all in simple setting like this.

### Traits

Context bounds are just syntactic sugar for an implicit parameter. The implicit value is passed where you define the type bound. I.e. if it is the type parameter of a method it is passed to the method.

A trait may not have any constructor parameters as due to linearisation you do not no where it will end up in the inheritance hierarchy. Thus it may not have any implicit parameters or type bounds either.

So you really have to add an implicit parameter to both methods.
If you are implementing some complex API this is fine, if this appears a lot in user code, maybe you can change your design.

### Classes

You can use context bounds for type parameters of classes, however the implicit parameter will not be directly used inside of methods of that class. To achieve that you have to provide a local implicit conversion like this:

```
class FooBar[T: Printable] {

    implicit def conv(x: T) = implicitly[Printable[T]]

    def foo(x: T) = {
        println("Running foo...")
        x.print()
    }
    def bar(x: T) = {
        println("But running bar first...")
        foo(x)
    }
}
```

### View Bounds

There are also view bounds as an alternative. They have however been deprecated. If you run scalac with -Xfuture it will show you that.

Comment: In this case you need to use view bounds, not context bounds, to pass the implicit parameter around: `def bar[T <% Printable](x: T) = foo(x)`. However, view bounds are deprecated as of Scala 2.11.

Comment: Thanks, I understand your answer. I added an extra question regarding this topic in my original one. Is there a solution for that one also?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is the type `T`.
Means, that without

```
(implicit ev: T => Printable[T])
```

the compiler tries to find an implicit that would work for any type of `T`
which he can not, because there is an implicit only for `Double`.

But if you add

```
(implicit ev: T => Printable[T])
```

the compiler tries to find the implicit at the place you call bar.
And if you call it with a `Double` parameter he takes `doubleToPrint` and passes it by.